# Install c/c++ compiler just like turbo c or dev c++

Tags: 12.04

Hye. I used to do programming in windows but now I am switched to Linux. I tried to get the IDE of c/c++ from Ubuntu software center but it is also not providing me any IDE for c/c++. I want to Install c/c++ IDE just like turbo c or Dev c++ in Ubuntu...

Comment: You want a IDE or you want... what you want?

Comment: the gcc is installed by default in Ubuntu, if that's what you want, if not tell us!

Comment: Your google-foo must be pretty weak :-/ [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79210/best-c-ide-for-nix) is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu, you can install every dev tools with the build-essential package.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

You have to choise when you do C/C++ on linux. Use a text editor with each dev tools individualy or use a IDE that include the text editor and all needed tools.

Good editors:

- Vim
- emacs
- Geany
- Scite
- sublime text

Good IDE:

- Code::Block
- Netbeans
- Eclipse
- QtCreator

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, try searching for **Code::Blocks, Netbeans** or **Geany** in the Ubuntu Software Center, for example. These are IDEs for C/C++.